# Scala Play injecting repository into controller

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

my Repository

```
import domain.{Db, User, UsersTable}
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile


class UsersRepository(val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile])
  extends Db with UsersTable {

  import config.profile.api._

  def insert(user: User) = db.run(users += user)

}
```

domain/User

```
import play.api.libs.json.{ Json}

case class User (id:Long ,firstName: String, lastName:String)

object User {
  implicit val writeUser = Json.writes[User]
  implicit val readUser = Json.reads[User]
  implicit val formatUser = Json.format[User]
}
```

UsersTable

```
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import services.UserTable

trait Db {
  val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  val db: JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = config.db
}

trait UsersTable { this: Db =>
  import config.profile.api._
  private class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def firstName = column[String]("first_name")

    def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
    // Select
    def * = (id, firstName, lastName) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
  }
  val users = TableQuery[UserTable]
}
```

Lets say i inject that repo here

```
class UserController @Inject()(repo: UsersRepository, cc: ControllerComponents, parsers: PlayBodyParsers)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {
```

im getting this error

```
Could not find a suitable constructor in repository.UsersRepository. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
```

As you can tell i'm not scala programmer, so any help is appreciated
Btw i was follwing this [article](https://medium.com/@kennajenifer1234/scala-tutorial-create-crud-with-slick-and-mysql-1b0a5092899f) to get to this place.

Answer (score 1):

as the exception suggests: `..constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.` you must change the constructor of the Repository to:

```
class UsersRepository @Inject()(val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile])
  extends Db with UsersTable {

  ...
}
```

If this still gives an error, that means that `DatabaseConfig` can not be injected. You can use then `UsersRepository` like:

```
class UsersRepository
  extends Db with UsersTable {

  val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = ??? //actual implementation
}
```

Or provide an Implementation that fits `DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]`

Comment: It's worth noting that UsersRepository could also be turned into a `trait` and config just be a value within the trait, though this would mean that you'd have to bind this trait to another class using `@ImplementedBy`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what im getting if i try to inject that config

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for slick.basic.DatabaseConfig<slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile> was bound.
  while locating slick.basic.DatabaseConfig<slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile>
    for the 1st parameter of repository.UsersRepository.<init>(UsersRepository.scala:11)
  while locating repository.UsersRepository
    for the 1st parameter of services.UserService.<init>(UserService.scala:31)
  while locating services.UserService
    for the 1st parameter of controllers.UserController.<init>(UserController.scala:15)
  while locating controllers.UserController
    for the 3rd parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:29)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:121):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

1 error
```